# Python Reverse escaped char - Make a variable into raw string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, escaping, literals

Note: This is a hypothetical question:
So I Googled several variations of this question ("String literl", "Escape Char", "Raw String", etc), mainly only solution they said was to place a "r" before the first quote of a string. I also tried using .format() into a raw string, re/repr, and I tried .replace() the slashes, but it already converts the escape char.

```
path = r"C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python_2.7\2016\MyProgram"
os.path.exists( path ) # Return True
os.listdir( path ) # Returns list of files in directory
```

However, what if it was a pre-defined variable returned from a separate function/class (for example)?

```
path = Class.Function.GetPath()
os.path.exists( path ) ## Returns False
os.listdir(path) ## Will print something like: 
## Windows Error... "C:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\Python_2.7\x816\\MyProgram"
```

So my question is: How do you make a pre defined variable a string literal, and get something like this path to work?

Update: This is all hypothetical! Just curious if there is a way to reverse escaped chars!!!

Example:

```
s = "\x77"
print s  ## Prints "w"
len(s)  ## Returns 1

MagicFunction(s)  ## Returns "\x77" ???
```

Comment: There is a difference between a *string* and a *string literal*...

Comment: A raw string literal is just a different way to create a string. Like hexadecimal notation is a different way to create a number. It doesn't matter if you write `num = 15` or `num = 0xf`, the result is always the integer 15. Similarly, `string = r"something"` is still a normal string.

Comment: `r"C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python_2.7\2016\MyProgram"` and `"C:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\Python_2.7\\2016\\MyProgram"` **are the exact same string**. Literally precisely identical. No difference between how they act when used whatsoever, on account of which this question seems to be based on a misconception.

Comment: You can test this yourself: Run `print repr(r"C:\Users\Chris\Documents")` to see how Python will represent a variable with that value at the REPL.

Comment: ...the double-backslash sequence is just how a single literal backslash is printed (when generating a Python-format representation of a string's contents), same as `\t` is the way a literal tab is printed, `\n` is the way a literal newline is printed, etc.

Comment: The error is inside `Class.Function.GetPath()`. How is the method defined?

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand your question. Is the output of `Class.Function.GetPath ()` returning a string, or the raw data? Test to make sure it's a string. If it isnt simply cast the return value as `str`.

```
path = str(Class.Function.GetPath()) # Make sure the variable is a string
print os.path.exists( path ) # Check the location
print os.listdir(path)

# repr vs str
print path         # path is already an str data type.
print repr(path)   # Shows the true string value.
```

If there was a newline character the only way to display it is to cancel out the functionality by adding another backslash represented as `'\\n` instead of '\n'.

Comment: The function would hypothetically return a string, and store it into a variable, then later it would be used in things like os.listdir(). But I think that part about using double backslash might be worth looking into. Thanks

Comment: Explicitly cast it as a string just in case. When returning from a function you  never know what data type your going to get.

Comment: Or hardcode it into the function `GetPath (): return str(value)`

Answer (score 0):

From the question:

> ```
> s = "\x77"
> print s  ## Prints "w"
> len(s)  ## Returns 1
>
> MagicFunction(s)  ## Returns "\x77" ???
> ```

The variable `s` stores the string "w". There are several ways to write the [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

- `"w"`
- `"\x77"`
- `"\167"`

Unicode strings add:

- `"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER W}"`
- `"\u0077"`
- `"\U00000077"`

The variable just contains the string with one character "w". The information, how the input was written in the input file is lost. Therefore, `MagicFunction` could only return a list all possible forms without knowing the original form.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. So I guess a better question would be: What format/coding is "\x77"? Cause if we know that, then we can easily convert it back, right?

Comment: @ChrisNguyen Maybe, it is easier to understand with numbers: `a = 1`, `a = 01`, `a = 000000001` all store the same number 1 into the variable `a`. But, the variable does not know about the leading zeros